# How to use Character.UnicodeBlock while I set some strings in a JEditorpane

Tags: java, swing, unicode, jeditorpane

I need to display some Bengali characters. I've tried to set the font to a Bengali Unicode font but It does not work properly. The last hope to fulfill my project is to use `Character.UnicodeBlock`. But I do not have any idea about it. Is it really possible to get the actual display of any Unicode character in Java? How can I use `Character.UnicodeBlock` in a component?

Comment: `Character.UnicodeBlock` has nothing to do with font rendering; it is only for identifying where in the Unicode range a code point belongs.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Obviously hard code a short Bengali phrase in Unicode for us to test with.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : ইংৰাজী বৰ্ণমালাৰ আদ্যাক্ষৰ : This is a sample phrase. It should be as it shown in browser. I am using Kalpurush.ttf Can it be a problem of font ?

Comment: An MCVE is code.  Please read the linked document.

Answer (score 0):

I assume Java 7.

First one needs a Unicode font.

If this font goes into the Windows fonts, and there is no name clash with an already existing font, everything should work.

Otherwise one might store the font as resource file in the application:

```
InputStream fontIn = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/.../... .ttf");
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, file);
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(font);
```

After this `jEditorPane.setFont(font)` should work. Mind, the text in the JEditorPane should not be HTML, where own fonts might be set.

It is tricky, because of font substitution, on font decoding using names.

Another problem might be hard-coded strings in the java source: the encoding of the java source (the editor) must be the same as is used by the javac compiler. For international projects best both UTF-8 (`javac -encoding=UTF-8 ...`). To test whether there is a problem with that one can test with `"\u099C"` for `জ`.